# If I have an equation of degree 2 or 3 and one of the coefficients is unknown, how to find that coefficient giving that one of the poles is given.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, $S^3 + 3S^2 + 18S + K$

Given that one of the roots is $-10$. How would you find K that satisfies this condition?

Comment: The degree doesn't matter. The method described in the answers applies for any polynomial with a single unknown coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

substitute $S=-10$ in $S^3 + 3S^2 + 18S + K$ and find $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the roots is $-10$, then that means exactly that
$$
(-10)^3 +3(-10)^2+18(-10)+K=0
$$
Now you can just calculate.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! 
K = 880.
I tried solving it with my calculator and it gave me the roots which one of them is -10.